# Css grid auto-flow minmax with outer columns

Tags: css, css-grid

Hi I'd like to use grid's `repeat` and `auto-fill` but with an *outer columns* left and right set to `1vw` (vertical width unit) to create some *padding*.

Not sure how to set the *grid items* to use the `auto-fill` *columns* and ignore the *columns* set to `1vw`.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1vw repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px , 1fr)) 1vw;
  grid-gap: 0.5vw;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  background: peachpuff;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not the padding or margin ?  if you intend to leave these areas empty.

Comment: Using 1vw makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If were creating a less responsive grid, I could code the following layout:
grid-template-columns: 1vw repeat(12, 1fr) 1vw
Giving me the flexible gap on either side of the 12 column grid. I could use margin or padding but would like to use grid syntax if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking this. Just give the `ul` left/right `margin` of `1vw` and remove those grid-columns completely. Or even simpler, a `width` of `98vw` and `margin:auto`

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: auto;
  width:98vw;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px , 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.5vw;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  background: peachpuff;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
  <li>Grid Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yep, guilty as charged. Thanks for your time.